# Read JSON as string from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, microsoft.extensions.configuration

Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration has its own API for navigating through the JSON contained in the config file it reads in. (This is what ASP.NET uses for configuration)

For a given JSON node- is there a way to get access to its contents as a string rather than as more Configuration objects? I have JSON objects in my config file which I need to run through a JSON deserializer (so I just want to read this node from the file as a string).

Something akin to the following:

```
var myObjectsSection = configuration.GetSection("MyObjects");
var innerText = myObjectsSection.InnerText; //Is there any way to do this???
var myObjs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject[]>(innerText);
```

Config file:

```
{
   "SomeSetting": "mySetting",
   "MyObjects": [
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net core 3 has a method for getting type-related configuration value: `T IConfigurationSection.Get<T>()`

I've tried to parse the custom configuration which you described and it is working.

appsetting.json:

```
{
  "CustomSection": [
    {
      "SomeProperty": 1,
      "SomeOtherProperty": "value1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Startup class:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            IConfigurationSection section = this.Configuration.GetSection("CustomSection");
            var configs = section.Get<List<CustomSectionClass>>();
        }

        public class CustomSectionClass
        {
            public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
            
            public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
        }
    }
```